# vertical align style for text

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

Hi there I'm working on an ASP.NET\ c# app;

I have a page with a div at the bottom just to show error\success messages to end user.
These messages go into an asp label inside this div. 
I need those messages to be vertically aligned and so far i had no success. 
Vertical- align doesn't seem to work with IE.

Any tip on that?

tks

Comment: can you post the html/css code you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

What about using

```
line-height: /*parent height*/
```

On the parent element

Answer (score 0):

Set `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: center`  in the css for the elements that hold the text.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to create an html table inside your DIV.
Then you can use the `valign` within the `<td>`.

If you need further illustration, you need to post your html so that we can help

Sample code:

```
<div>
    <table id="id1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
    <tr>
          <td width="100%" valign="middle">Your message goes here....</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, tks for your answer, but it doesn't solve my problem completely. If my message ocupates, for example, to lines, only the first line seems centered and the second line is cuted... ='( ='( ='(

Comment: It's considered bad practice to use tables for layout.